Problems repeating Shekhar's calculations in his article on Asymmetric and Post Quantum Cryptography
This is a great article at
https://medium.com/@shekhar.siva2609/asymmetric-encryption-and-post-quantum-cryptography-bea4a5a08ae5,
particularly if you're interested in Elliptic curve cryptography.
However, I'm having trouble repeating the calculations for (A*s + e)mod(x^4+1) where
A = [6x^3 + 16x^2 + 16x + 11   9x^3 + 4x^2 + 6x + 3
5x^3 +3x^2 + 10x + 1       6x^3 + x^2 + 9x + 15]
s = (-x^3 -x^2 +x,  -x^3 -x)
e = (x^2, x^2 -x)
I'm assuming dimensions: A:(2x2), s:(2x1),  e:(2x1),  ans:(2x1) for the matrix polynomial products
He gets:(16x³ + 15x² + 7, 10x³ + 12x² + 11x + 6)
I am getting (41+34x+15x^2-18x^3,  23-6x+12x^2-24x^3)
Sorry it's a bit maths-heavy but I wrote my own code to process polynomials and tested it pretty thoroughly, including algebraic moduli.

The matrix A didn't print out well. The first row has 2 entries: 6x^3 + 16x^2 + 16x + 11 and 9x^3 + 4x^2 + 6x + 3

The second row is
5x^3 +3x^2 + 10x + 1 and 6x^3 + x^2 + 9x + 15
